# How to rename controls rapidly in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I´m looking for a way to rename a bunch of controls, which is the fastest way?

Also, is it possible to change the name prefix of the controls to a custom one like so:

| Properties |

(Name) | TextBox1

to:

(Name) | txt1

as default name when inserting the controls on a form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer to #2 is "no," that is not possible.

As to a fast way to rename controls, you can go into the text view of the form designer and do an incremental search to move from name to name, so you don't have to click each control and then go back to the property grid.

A bit more intuitive would be to use the **Document Outline** pane. This is a much faster way to move from control to control and you can rename them in-place instead of going to the property grid. It also has the advantage that you can see by the selection indicator in the designer which control you have selected in the document outline and vice versa.

By default, navigate to `View -> Other Windows -> Document Outline`.

Here is a screenshot. I know you are using VS2010 and this is VS2012, but it works the same way:
[image]

Comment: I'm surprised no-one has mentioned Refactor > Rename. It seems to me that this would be safer. Is there a known issue with doing a rename on form elements?

Answer (score 0):

"Replace in Files" which can be found by shift+ctrl+H would be the easiest way to rename all "TextBox" to "txt".

As for the second point, you could either hand-code the controls to use your prefix or write some kind of Visual Studio add-in that would do the translation for you would be the approach I'd take.